# Haskell cross-platform getChar with NoBuffering

Tags: windows, haskell, io, ghc

Haskell has [a bug in Windows](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/2189) that seems [fixed with WinIO in GHC9](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/merge_requests/1224): getChar ignores NoBuffering mode - it does not evaluate until Enter is pressed.

Somebody [suggested](https://exceptionshub.com/haskell-read-input-character-from-console-immediately-not-after-newline.html) a workaround via a foreign call:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
import Data.Char
import Foreign.C.Types
getHiddenChar = fmap (chr.fromEnum) c_getch
foreign import ccall unsafe "conio.h getch"
  c_getch :: IO CInt
```

It kind of works, but the problem is that it seems to block the output to console until some key is pressed, and I am concurrently reading key presses and writing to console from different threads.

Could you please help find a way (e.g. write a foreign function call - I do not know much about it, unfortunately) to read characters/keys from console, without buffering and echo, and without blocking output to console, in GHC 8.8.x (or at least 8.10.x), on Windows?

Thank you!

(Ideally I need a cross-platform way, but I can do it via conditional compilation, so if it only works on Windows it is ok. Above foreign call is not cross-platform already).

Answer (score 1):

I've found the library that does it: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/terminal

It does not block while waiting for key presses, you can still print from another thread.

It also solves Windows terminal [utf8 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66928909/utf-8-input-output-in-from-haskell-in-windows/66958732#66958732).

Answer (score 1):

The essential problem with that particular FFI call is the `unsafe`. That makes the `getch` happen in the calling (system) thread. As a rule, foreign calls that may take some time should be marked `safe`. Even that is a bit problematic, because exceptions (e.g., from the user hitting Ctrl-C) are masked.

The true solution for such FFI calls is to mark them `interruptible` and then deal with interruption properly. You do this by checking whether the call was successful (based on its return value). If it wasn't, then you'd check `errno` for `EINTR` and try again in that case, as for any foreign call of that sort. But for an `interruptible` one, if you get `EINTR` you should deliver asynchronous exceptions using `allowInterrupt` before retrying.

Caveat: the above approach only works for foreign calls that are (mostly) making interruptible system calls, and that terminate with a failure status and set EINTR when interrupted. A foreign function performing an expensive mathematical computation, for example, is not generally interruptible at all.

Caution: mixing `Handle`-based I/O with raw FFI I/O on the same file descriptor sounds like a recipe for trouble.

Comment: > mixing Handle-based I/O with raw FFI I/O on the same file descriptor sounds like a recipe for trouble.
Even if only one thread does writing, only via handle, and another thread does reading, only via FFI?

Comment: @esp, that I couldn't say for sure. Might be fine, but I'm not an expert in that aspect.