# UTF-8 input/output in from Haskell in Windows

Tags: haskell, utf-8, terminal, console

Simple code below does not work correctly in Windows terminal with UTF-8 characters, whether with getLine/putStrLn from Prelude or from Data.Text.IO:

```hs
main = forever $ getLine >>= putStrLn
```

It echoes utf-8 characters during the input, then it prints "?"s in place of utf-8 characters; switching encoding with `chcp 65001` makes them spaces.

I've downloaded the new terminal and enabled utf-8 support as [this page](https://akr.am/blog/posts/using-utf-8-in-the-windows-terminal) suggested, but it had no effect.

[This explanation](https://exceptionshub.com/unicode-console-io-in-haskell-on-windows.html) seems related, but the solution proposed there does not work (the code does the same).

Apparently python has a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878972/windows-cmd-encoding-change-causes-python-crash/3259271#3259271)

Is there any library/workaround that would work with GHC 8.x?

Please help!

EDIT: after more investigation, the problem is during the input as well - if instead of putStrLn I print character codes with `mapM_ (print . ord) s` they are all either 63 without changing encoding or 0 after `chcp 65001`.

`hSetEncoding stdin utf8` does not help

Comment: Which windows version are you using?

Comment: It is windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the library that does it: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/terminal

It does not include getLine (only key events), but it's simple enough to implement:

```hs
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import System.Exit (exitSuccess)
import System.Terminal as C

getTermLine :: MonadTerminal m => m String
getTermLine = getChars ""
  where
    getChars s = awaitEvent >>= processKey s
    processKey s = \case
      Right (KeyEvent key ms) -> case key of
        CharKey c
          | ms == mempty || ms == shiftKey -> do
            C.putChar c
            flush -- works without flush in Windows, but not in Mac
            getChars (c : s)
          | otherwise -> getChars s
        EnterKey -> do
          putLn
          flush
          pure $ reverse s
        BackspaceKey -> do
          moveCursorBackward 1
          eraseChars 1
          flush
          getChars $ if null s then s else tail s
        _ -> getChars s
      Left Interrupt -> liftIO exitSuccess
      _ -> getChars s
```